# Zend Controller Router passing variables

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I want to route the /market-research/ to /index/index/slide/2

So I want to pass this value 2 for the 'slide' parameter

```
    $routemr = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
        'market-research',
        array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
    );
    $router->addRoute('market-research', $routemr);
```

How can I do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following :

```
 $router = $frontController->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
            '/market-research',
        array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'type' => 'slide', //default value (im using 'type' just as an example)
            'id' => 2, //default value

        ));
    $router->addRoute('market-research', $route);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$router = $this->_front->getRouter();
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'market-research/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'slide' => 2
    )
);
$router->addRoute('index-marketresearch', $route);
```